# How can I run command line CoreNLP in multi-threads?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I need to parse a lot of documents (around 0.3 million).
As suggested in the stanford web, I created a file named filelist.txt which contains paths of all the files to be parsed.

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html

Then I called the CoreNLP as below.

```
java -mx20g -cp "$SCRIPT/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse -ssplit.eolonly tokenize.whitespace true -filelist filelist.txt -outputDirectory $OUTDIR
```

But the CPU usage is just 100%, which means CoreNLP seems not to use multi-threads. Thus, the parsing is too slow (approximately 10sec per document.).

When I run CoreNLP without -filelist option, it runs as multi-threads.

Is there any options or ways to use multi threads in CoreNLP?

Comment: The problem is solved by the answer from Gabor. I could just use -threads option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the command line argument `-threads k` should annotate a file list on `k` threads.

Comment: Thanks Gabor. The option -threads properly solved the problem.